# Using PHP to Run exe and then provide the user with his file

Tags: php, exe

I'm currently writing a php file that uses an exe and feeds it arguments such as file name and a few integers
my question is, how do i enable the exe file access to the file my user provided through the php file and also my exe creates a new file, what do i do so that the user will receive the new file to save it on his computer?

thanks in advance

Comment: @exec('C:\dir\yourexe.exe', $output);

Comment: echo var_dump($output);

Comment: @David: Don't use the operator of death (`@`), pass the status parameter to `exec`, check its value and handle any unexpected exit codes that way + escape your backslashes (`exec('C:\\dir\\some\\bin.exe', $out, $status);`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Don't use the operator of death (@) why, im curios, i added @ infront of it, because sometime only exec is not working.

Comment: @David: if a function call or your accessing a variable (ie an non-existing array index) issues a notice, PHP is basically telling you there might be a bug in your code, don't suppress it, don't ignore it. Fix it. Besides even when using `@`, the notice or warning is still being issued, it is only silenced at the last possible moment. That means it slows you down (significantly). Notices are there for one reason only: to help you improve your code and spot typo's before they give you grief. Use it to your advantage

Comment: Suppose I have an array like `$foo = ['bar' => 123];` and I were to write `echo $foo['var'];` (typo). The notice will tell me _"undefined index at line..."_, changing the code to `echo @$foo['var'];` will hide the notice, but will echo nothing, instead of the expected 123. It's a bug. In this case, it's not _too_ bad, but when inserting data in the DB, or when incrementing a value that actually matters, it will give you grief

Comment: To the OP: if you can, don't have the exe generate the new file on your file-system, but have it return the output, then use the `$output` argument of `exec`, and send the file using `header` to set the mime-types accordingly